# Cannot run program "aapt"

Tags: android, apk, aapt, zipalign

I am trying to sign and zip align the android apk using terminal but I am getting following exception.

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "aapt": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at com.comarch.certificategenerator.GeneratorMainWindow.getPackageInfo(Unknown Source)
        at com.comarch.certificategenerator.GeneratorMainWindow.generateAppId(Unknown Source)
        at com.comarch.certificategenerator.GeneratorMainWindow.main(Unknown Source)
        at com.comarch.certificategenerator.Main.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
        ... 5 more            
Executing:
```

I tried to find but not understand why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

From Oracle documentation: "Verify that the location defined in the Android Build Tools Location field of the ADF Mobile Platforms page references the directory that contains the aapt file (aapt.exe on Windows systems). For Revision 22 of the Android SDK, this file, along with all of the other build tools components, is located within the build-tools directory. For earlier revisions, the build tools components are located in the platform-tools directory."
Probably, if you have updated your android build tools, the location is wrong and must to be changed in platform tools.
If you are running under linux system, maybe you're missing 32bit libraries: try with
 `sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib lib32z1 lib32stdc++6`